# trigamma fuction

Tags: special-functions

Explain me please why the equality $\ \displaystyle\psi_1(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac 1{(z+n)^2}\ $ is right if we 
define trigamma function like this : $\ \displaystyle\psi_1(z)=\frac{d^2}{dz^2}\ln\Gamma(z)$.

Comment: This depends on your definition of the gamma function... do you know about the Weierstrass product definition?

Comment: No. Can you give me link on some literature where i can read about my question?

Answer (score 2):

There is an easy way to come at the first equation if you note that :
$$\Gamma(z+1)=z\;\Gamma(z)$$
so that 
$$\ln\Gamma(z+1)=\ln(z)+\ln\Gamma(z)$$
Differentiation gives
$$\psi(z+1)=\frac 1z+\psi(z)$$
Differentiating again :
$$\psi_1(z+1)=-\frac 1{z^2}+\psi_1(z)$$
so that 
$$\psi_1(z)=\frac 1{z^2}+\psi_1(z+1)$$
$$\psi_1(z)=\frac 1{z^2}+\frac 1{(z+1)^2}+\psi_1(z+2)$$
$$\psi_1(z)=\frac 1{z^2}+\frac 1{(z+1)^2}+\frac 1{(z+2)^2}+\cdots$$

I hope that this will be a help too for your intuition !

Comment: (Out of votes today, so an IOU for now.) Repeatedly applying the functional equation is very much expedient. :D

Comment: Thanks for the intention anyway J.M. !